# How to configure hub uri to mvc controller in tfs 2017 extension

Tags: plugins, uri

I try to add extension to tfs 2017.

I created mvc web application and uploaded assembly to bin directory to tfs (and it normally opened by direct link "http://currentip/tfs/{collectionname/{projectname}/controllername" being processed in controller and displaying view)

Also I added hub group and hub, that normally displayed.
When clicking hub I need to be redirected to relative uri like http://currentip/tfs/{collectionname/{projectname}/controllername

But now I'm always redirected to http://ip/tfs/{collectionname/{projectname}/_apps/hub/extensionname-hubgroup-hub.

How can i configure link of hub to redirect to my controller in the same server?

ps. I made attention to "base uri" core parameter of extension. But there is too pure info about it on official help page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **uri**    path (relative to the extension's baseUri) of the page to surface as the hub.

You could set only *.html files(*html page to be used for your hub*) that described in the your extension's manifest file: `vss-extension.json` . Can't not configured the detail uri yourself. Since it will be loaded from VSTS or TFS server.

Actually **baseuri** is used for local debug/develop your extension. Without this, for every small change you make, you need to completely redeploy the package and then use your browser to validate the changes.

When you add this property, you **override** the default location of your assets. By letting this property point to your local host you can serve the files locally and your extension will load them into the context of VSTS or TFS.

After you  finished with development, just remove the baseUri from your manifest file and publish the extension to the marketplace. Afraid this is not helpful in your case. More details please refer this tutorial: [Using BaseUri to develop your VSTS extension](https://wouterdekort.com/2017/01/27/using-baseuri-to-develop-your-vsts-extension/)